# Qual a origem da expressão "dia de branco"?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica, origem, ditados, expressões-populares

Sempre ouvi a expressão

> Preciso dormir cedo, pois amanhã é *dia de branco*!

ou,

> Preciso ir pra casa, pois amanhã é *dia de branco*!

ou ainda,

> Sexta-feira também é *dia de branco*!

com o sentido de *ir à escola* (em alusão às fardas/uniformes) e, por extensão, ter um compromisso logo cedo, uma rotina a ser cumprida.

Outro dia fui chamado de *preconceituoso* por usar tal expressão.
Na interpretação do meu interlocutor, a expressão pode ser entendida como

> [...] é *dia de [homem] branco*!

aludindo às pessoas brancas.

Expliquei à pessoa qual o [meu] sentido da expressão, mas a explicação não pareceu convencê-la.

Alguém sabe qual a origem da expressão?

Comment: algumas referencias -> https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/dia+de+branco/
https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-da-expressao-dia-de-branco/27816
https://correionago.com.br/portal/hoje-e-dia-de-branco-dia-de-trabalhar/

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido tal coisa, curioso.

Comment: @JorgeB.  Nem eu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Desconheço a origem, mas desde os anos 1980-90 sempre vi entendido como sinônimo de "dia de trabalhar", com "branco" em oposição ao "negro", tido como preguiçoso.
Ou seja, de fato racista, juntamente com "serviço de preto", usado como sinônimo de "serviço mal feito", entre [outros](https://pragmatismo.jusbrasil.com.br/noticias/191503582/13-expressoes-racistas-que-precisam-sair-do-seu-vocabulario).

É importante lembrar que, ainda que a expressão tenha uma origem diferente, não racista, e ainda que a intenção também tenha sido não racista, é claro que a expressão é amplamente entendida como tal: e portanto ela **é** racista, porque é assim que ofensas funcionam — dizer que me refiro a uma caixinha quando, irritado, eu soltar um "boceta", não vai convencer muitos brasileiros de que não estou xingando, usando uma palavra chula para "vulva".

Portanto, se o desejo for se expressar de uma maneira respeitosa, melhor evitar tais expressões.

Comment: Olha, enchi-te isto de vírgulas (eu que me ando sempre a queixar da virgulite aguda dos outros), porque tive mesmo que ler a frase umas vezes para ter a certeza de que compreendi.

Comment: Boa respota. O racismo está ligado a quem ouve e não a quem diz. Várias expressões que via sendo utilizadas nos anos 90, atualmente são racistas.

Comment: Obrigado @Jacinto. As frases estão mesmo longas e concordo que as vírgulas melhoram a legibilidade (e não me enchestes de vírgulas, foram só duas :-) ).

Comment: Duas para mim já é muito. Foi também, ou sobretudo, eu não estar familiarizado com o contexto. O pessoal aqui não solta bocetas, nem mesmo quando estão contrariados, e momentaneamente fiquei: soltar a boceta não convence ou, como depois vi que tinha de ser, dizer que é caixinha não convence? Aí, a boceta seria insulto a quem contraria, ou desabafo do tipo, "boceta, esqueci-me outra vez das chaves em casa"?

Comment: @Jacinto Troquei "contrariado" por "irritado", talvez ajude. "Boceta" é um palavrão bem chulo em pt-br, muito pior que soltar um "merda", por exemplo.

Comment: Possivelmente é mais antiga que isso. Minha avó tem 89 anos e volta e meia diz "amanhã é dia de branco", ou seja, dia de trabalhar. Ela não sabe a origem e quando fala costuma se perguntar também de onde será que ela se origina mas desconfio dessa possível origem racista.

Comment: Sim, sim, sem dúvida é bem mais antiga, @Piovezan, só mencionei minha experiência pessoal (que não se estende a períodos anteriores aos anos 80 :-) ), o melhor seria pesquisar pela ocorrência da expressão em algum corpus.

Answer (score 1):

A origem é doméstica, referindo-se ao dia de lavagem das roupas de cama, antes todas brancas, que ornavam os varais, sendo motivo para o descanso mais cedo na véspera, pois a lavagem era feita nos tanques e no muque. Vou embora para casa mais cedo, porque amanhã é dia de branco. Portanto a expressão, como alguns podem pensar, não tem cunho racista.

Comment: Tércio, bem-vindo ao "Língua Portuguesa".. Aqui é importante as respostas serem fundamentadas. Como sabes que é essa a origem da expressão?

Answer (score 0):

O terno de linho branco era obrigatório em todos os trabalhos.Dai a expressão "amanhã é dia de branco," quer dizer, dia de trabalho

Comment: Uma afirmação destas precisa de ser apoiada em fontes sólidas.

Answer (score 0):

A expressão significa que é dia de trabalhar e, diferente do que muitos pensam, não tem origem racista. O primeiro pensamento de quem ouve, porém, é de que ela surgiu por causa do preconceito de brancos contra negros. Dizem que a expressão surgiu na Marinha, por causa dos uniformes brancos que eles tinham que usar para trabalhar.

Comment: Jones, bem-vindo ao site. Como é que sabes que não tem origem racista? Neste site nós esperamos que as afirmações sejam fundamentadas.  "Dizem que..." não fundamento nenhuma origem. Olha as outras respostas e podes ver que se **dizem** várias outras coisas também.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Eis a explicação. A expressão nada tem a ver com racismo.

Comment: Muito bem, era praticamente mandatório vestir de branco para ir trabalhar. Mas também é verdade que havia o preconceito de que os negros eram preguiçosos. Como é que sabes qual destas coisas originou a expressão? Ou se alguma delas a originou?

Comment: Como é que a tua resposta é mais válida do que a seguinte: “Excerto de “Impressões do Brasil” no [Correio Paulistano, 13 de novembro de 1937](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=090972_08&pesq=%22negro%20pregui%C3%A7oso%20%C3%ADndio%22&pasta=ano%20193&pagfis=21386) : ‘A mão de obra, sem ser nem muito numerosa, nem muito boa (**o negro é preguiçoso, o índio imprestável**) apresenta a vantagem de ser extraordinariamente barata’. Eis a explicação. A expressão não tem nada a ver com vestimenta.”

Answer (score 0):

Ouvia meu sogro falando isso, por ele ser médico já entendia que ele queria dizer que era dia de trabalhar.

Um dia fui falar isso em uma roda de amigos e tinha um conhecido que me retrucou:

- É dia de preto também.

Ele se ofendeu mas creio que já é um ressentimento existente

Answer (score 0):

A expressão nasceu na marinha, qd o marinheiros estavam no último dia de folga diziam que amanhã é dia de branco,se referindo a roupa.

Comment: Marçal, bem-vindo ao site. A tese da origem na marinha já foi apresentada noutra resposta. E a tua resposta tem o mesmo problema que a outra: como é que sabes que foi por causa dos uniformes da marinha?

Answer (score -2):

“O terno de linho branco era obrigatório em todos os trabalhos.Dai a expressão "amanhã é dia de branco," quer dizer, dia de trabalho”

Verdade, na década de 1930/1940, principalmente nas repartições públicas.

Comment: Dieliz, uma afirmação destas precisa de ser apoiada em fontes sólidas.

Comment: Isto é um comentário sobre [outra resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8087/11260) - veja as aspas na citação. Não é uma resposta...